# Is it safe to pipe output of gnu parallel to a single file or pipe

Tags: parallel-processing, scripting, io-redirection

With a construct similar to

```
find . -type f -name '*log' \
| parallel grep 'somestuff'    
| moreComplexLineRearrangementScript
| sort
```

I am wondering whether the moreComplexLineRearrangementScript has the risk to see garbled lines due to the fact that several grep instance write into the same pipe without any buffer synchronization.

1. Can this be a problem for naive uses of grep as above or can I rely on the fact that grep's implementation writes lines always with a flush()?
2. If it not were grep, can there be some magic in `parallel` that does the flush()?
3. Is there a way to use `parallel` that guarantees lines to be kept intact --- apart from redirecting each parallel process' output to a separate file and then go from there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, **GNU Parallel** buffers output by job, so the output from different jobs is not all mixed up, that is:

```
parallel --group
```

If you want **GNU Parallel** to do line-at-a-time output, possibly mixing output from different jobs, but always in whole lines, use:

```
parallel --line-buffer
```

If you like your output really higgeldy-piggeldy and all mixed up even mid-line, use:

```
parallel --ungroup
```